# Is there a way to equate a raised exception with some other value

Tags: python, assert

I am trying python-koans:

There is an old style class defined:

```
class A:
    pass
```

We know that old style classes do not have `__class__` defined.

There is an assert statement provided which I am required to make pass.

```
self.assertEqual(__, A.__class__)
```

I am expected to fill some value in the blank, i.e first argument, so that it passes. `A.__class__` will raise an attribute error. How am I supposed to make this test pass?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) instead of trying to access `.__class__` directly. For old-style classes, this returns `types.ClassType`:

```
>>> from types import ClassType
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> type(Foo) is ClassType
True
```

Generally speaking, for every dunder (double underscore, `__...__`) name, there is a API function or operator that those hooks address. Use the API function or operator instead of accessing the hook directly. E.g. use `str(f)` instead of `f.__str__()`, etc.

If you are testing against exceptions, you probably want to use the [`assertRaises()` context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to test for specific exceptions:

```
with self.assertRaises(Foo) as cm:
     function_under_test()
```

You can then still access the exception instance as `cm.exception` for further testing.

Comment: Second argument is already provided and I am not expected to change it. Can I pass something as the first argument to `self.assertEqual()` to make this test pass?

Comment: @aksharraaj: you really want to use `is` here, but at a pinch `type(A) == types.ClassType` will work.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a terrible idea, but hey -- Python lets you do anything, right?**

```
assertEqual(setattr(A, "__class__", type) or type, A.__class__)
```

I think I might be cheating.

Answer (score 0):

This might be irrelevant but probable usecases are equating an exception's class with a particular exception class. Example code attached

```
try:
    1/0
except (ZeroDivisionError) as e:
    pass
#equate an exception with a class of exception
isinstance(e, ZeroDivisionError)
```